# MapStruct code generation to maven generate-source phase

Tags: maven-3, mapstruct

Is it possible to configure mapstruct to generate mappers in generate-sources instead of compile?

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct is an annotation processor. Which means that the code that is generated is generated by the Java Compiler during compilation. You need to check if there is a way to configure the maven compiler, or the gradle apt plugin in order to achieve this